# passing url parameter in django template using form

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm writing a page that takes an id and finds a user that matches that id.
this is the URL pattern that I wrote in **urls.py**:

```
re_path(r'^users/id=(?P<username>[0-9]{9})$' , views.usershow , name = 'usershow') ,
```

I want to pass username using forms and so I wrote this in **templates**:

```
<form action="{% url 'CMS:usershow' %}" method="GET" >
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="id" type="number" placeholder="search">
<button type="submit">find</button>
</form>
```

but it shows me this **error** :

```
Reverse for 'usershow' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/users/id=(?P<username>[0-9]{9})$']
```

How can I pass it using forms with this URL pattern?

Comment: Do you really have to pass `{% csrf_token %}` when your form method is `GET`? I think not.

Comment: @HassanBaig no. I tried post method before that and I forget to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how forms work. Remove the username from the pattern:

```
path(r'^users/' , views.usershow , name = 'usershow') ,
```

and in the view get the value from the request;

```
username = request.GET["id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure CMS app's **urls.py** is having the path.

Second, pass user id value as shown below:

```
<form action="{% url 'CMS:usershow' user_id %}" method="GET" >
```

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#s-reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: but I want to user enters the username with input.